# write in a vector through the same (ROS) callback using boost::bind (C++)

Tags: c++, boost, ros

i'm using ROS topics in order to acquire some image streams from a simulator.
the idea is the following: i have "n" visual sensors and i'd like to declare n subscriber (through a for cycle) that read n **different** topics and call the **same** callback: passing an integer to the c.b. i'll be able to fill a vector of images (each of them received on a different topic).

this is my code:

```
vector <IplImage*> Images;

void newImageTrigger_trgI(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg, int i)
{
 cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;


try
{

    cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, enc::BGR8);

    Images[i] = cv_ptr->image;


}
catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
{
    ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
}

}


 int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {


ros::init(argc, argv, "ImageProcessing");
ros::NodeHandle n;

    std::vector<ros::Subscriber> sub;
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    string str_i=string_converter(i);
     sub[i] = n.subscribe("/vrep/visionSensorData"+str_i, 1,...   //ERROR
       boost::bind(&newImageTrigger_trgI, _1, i));
     }

      .....
```

Obviously: "invalid arguments" at //ERROR

can someone help me please?...i think it's something concerning boost::bind function
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The subscribe function in the erroneous line needs to be explicitly instantiated for the type sensor_msgs::Image in this case:

```
sub[i] = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Image>("/vrep/visionSensorData"+str_i, 1, boost::bind(&newImageTrigger_trgI, _1, i));
```